# IKEv2 client on Alpine?

Tags: vpn, docker

I'm trying to connect a docker container to a IKEv2 vpn (algo).  But googling hasn't helped me in figuring out how to use alpine as a client.

How can I set up alpine 3.8 to be a IKEv2 VPN client?

Or if there's a better way to route all the traffic from only one docker container through the VPN, I'm listening.

Note:  I also tried wireguard, and it could connect to it, but it would say the DNS was invalid (probably because it used the same subnet as docker).